# Проверка на пустоту

Tags: поиск, sql

всем привет, делаю поиск для каталога телефонов, поиск идёт по нескольким полям. Нужно сделать поиск по телефонам у которых в бд поле camera, не пустое
Вот sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `phone` WHERE `model` LIKE :model OR `id_firm` LIKE :firm AND `camera`!=''
```

Вот думаю насколько такой запрос правильный

Answer (score 4):

Может так?

```
WHERE 'camera' IS NOT NULL
```